# Can I interchange my "Home, End" keys with "PageUp, PageDown" keys on dell latitude laptop?

Tags: windows, keyboard, key-binding

The Home,End keys are at the top row in my laptop, and I use them most while selecting the entire line by pressing (Shift+Home, Shift+End) - it is very inconvenient. On the other hand, "PageUp, PageDown" keys are just below the Shift Key, and I don't use them at all.

Can I interchange my "PageUp" key with "Home" key and "PageDown" key with "End" key?

Is this possible using some software?

Comment: Yes. Which operating system?

Comment: Windows 7 Professional

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since you are on Windows, I recommend [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/).

Once installed you can remap <kbd>Home</kbd> to <kbd>PageUp</kbd>, <kbd>End</kbd> to <kbd>PageDown</kbd>, and vice versa, with a simple AutoHotKey script.

Just create a text file called `remapKeys.ahk` and execute (double click) it:

```
Home::PgUp
End::PgDn
PgUp::Home
PgDn::End
```

---

**Documentation:**

- [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/)
- [Remapping Keys and Buttons](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Building on iglvzx's answer about [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/), another option is to set up the arrow keys to act as PageUp, PageDown, Home, and End when the right shift keys is being pressed:

> ```
> +Up::send {RShift Up}{PgUp}
> +Down::send {RShift Up}{PgDn}
> +Left::send {RShift Up}{Home}
> +Right::send {RShift Up}{End}
> ```

(From http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/one-handed-page-up-page-down-on-a-laptop-with-no-dedicated-keys.760843/)

Answer (score 1):

[SharpKeys](http://sharpkeys.codeplex.com/) is a powerful tool that will automatically edit your registry to rebind keys. It won't need to run in the background like Auto Hot Key does.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be done easily, use the "**Windows Power Toys**". One simple solution for advanced windows users.

**Step 1**:- Install The Power Toys from the like given below.

**Step 2**:- Use the Key remap shortcuts for the mapping.

**Step 3**:- Use the + Button and remap the keys you want, restart your PC and you are done!

**Download Link**:- [This is the Link](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys/releases/tag/v0.29.3)

Answer (score 0):

[Key Tweak](http://keytweak.en.softonic.com/download) is a powerful tool that will automatically edit your registry to rebind keys. It won't need to run in the background like Auto Hot Key does.

Answer (score 0):

On windows, instead of third party tools, can consider the keyboard manager power toy: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/keyboard-manager

Similar configuration as the AutoHotKey answer by @iglvzx (you configure using GUI instaed of a config file).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1194436)